# Dog Fight Java implication

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

It has been a while that I done this sort of coding. So I was wondering if there was somewhere I have to make changes to allow me to make a proper java tester.

```
  public void performMove(Dog otherDog, float randomNumber) {


  /* Parameters for attack vs. Attack */
  if(!(this.isDefending)&&!(otherDog.isDefending)){
    if((randomNumber * 100) >= speed){
      otherDog.getHit((int)Math.round(0.25*power));
    }
    else{
      resultOfLastInteraction = "...." + this.name + "miss"; 
    }

  }
  /*Parameters for Attack vs. Defend*/
  else if(!(this.isDefending) && (otherDog.isDefending)){

    if((randomNumber * 100 >= 0) && (randomNumber * 100 <= 50)){
      otherDog.getHit((int)Math.round(0.25*power));
    }
    else if((randomNumber * 100 >= 51) && (randomNumber * 100 <= 75)){
      this.getHit((int)Math.round(0.25*power));
    }
    else if((randomNumber * 100 >= 76) && (randomNumber * 100 <= 100)){
      this.getHit((int)Math.round(0.25*power));

  }

    /*Parameters for Defend vs. Defend */
  else if((this.isDefending) && (otherDog.isDefending)){
    resultOfLastInteraction = "Stale Mate";
  }
  else{
    resultOfLastInteraction = "Select Move";
  }
  }

/* stubbed */

}
```

Comment: your `dog2.resultOfLastInteraction()` is returning NULL and is being not set.

Comment: You could improve your tests' readability if you learn about the `assertEquals` and `assertNotEquals` methods.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the implementation of `resultOfLastInteraction()` in the `Dog` class (I'm assuming it has a similar name to that), but it must be returning `null`.

Also, just for clarification, by "*returning* a `NullPointerException`", the proper terminology is to say *throwing* a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: public String resultOfLastInteraction() {

return resultOfLastInteraction;

}

Comment: @Carl Well I think it is safe to assume that `resultOfLastInteraction` is set to `null` at some point, or it isn't even being initialized at all.

Comment: well I also have in the implementation of the commands this:          else{
      resultOfLastInteraction = "...." + this.name + "miss"; 
    }

Comment: dog1.performMove(dog2, 0.6F);

This method should be setting the resultOfLastInteraction string in some way. Does each dog class have a method that's invoked when they receive an attack? It should be set there.

Comment: should I e-mail you the code I have so far? Cause somewhere tells me I screwed it up all together

Comment: Rather than email, how about you just update your question to show your code?

Comment: Does Stack Overflow do debugging?  I thought that's what debuggers were for.  I feel this question has been well answered already.